# Paper Texture in CSS?

Tags: css, photoshop, textures

Is it possible to make this texture in pure css?

[image]

See this also for texture: http://dribbble.com/shots/70256-Background-Textures

Comment: Yes, I do realize this isn't strictly programing related, but where else can I find a super-friendly group of helpful smart people?! :)

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com

Comment: @JohnB: What does that have to do with CSS?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you don't care about supporting older browsers, you can do this:

```
body {background:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAF8AAACcCAMAAAAu7ofdAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAtlQTFRFbnB2bW94bG50cHJ4bnF6a212cHN8c3V7dXd8c3Z+aGpzdXiAamxyb3F0d3l+bW9yZ2lyd3qCeXuAdnh7aGpwZWdwe32DZ2hteHl9eXyFb3F3bW91cnR6bnB5Y2VtbG53bW93e36HdHZ7bG52bnF5bW92cXN5cXR8dHd/bG51b3J7cnV9foCGb3J6YGNrbXB4dHZ8cnR7bnB3aWt0b3F4cXN6cHN7a211a21zb3J5bnF4dHZ9dnmBf4GHc3V8bXB3a210dXd9cHJ5cnV8bnB4cXN4cnR5amxzaWtzenyCb3F1c3Z9fX6BcXR9dnh9foGKdHd+cHN6b3F2fn+DcHJ2cXR7eHp/ZWZsdXd7dXd6aGpycnV+b3F5aWtxbnB0bnB1cHJ6bW90c3V6amx1dXh/cHJ3bXB2XWFpdnh+aWtyeHqAZmhxcHJ1gYOKd3l/bG5zaGpxcXN7bnBzZ2luc3V5bnF3bW9zamx0c3V9XGBodnh/dXh+cnV7dXd/b3J4cXR6cXN8b3F6dHZ6g4WMcnR8dHd9dniAdnh8dHeAcnR4ZGZudnmCeHuEZWZqfH6Ff4KMdnmAdXd+cHN5dHZ5gIKGaGpvdnl/dXh9d3mAaGlyaWtwe32Eb3J2d3h8Z2lxdHZ+c3Z/amxxWlxlfH6Ea21yeXuBd3l8eHuDd3qDcXN3ZmhwZmhvc3Z7cXR5cXN2bG5yd3qBcnV5bG9zen2DdXiBenuAd3l9Z2lvcHJ7dXZ6c3Z8bXB0fH2Cdnd7dHd8b3J1ZmhueXp/d3p/Z2huZGZtbXBzeHp+en2FfX6Ce32GXWFogoSNfYCKcnN4eHqBcXJ3dHZ/enyBc3R3X2Jre32CZWZteXyEfX+FZWduX2Jqd3mBbm91amxwen2Ge36GeXyDbm90foGJdnd8ZWdvcnR3ent/fX+GdXZ7fH+IfYCHc3R6eXt/fYCJZ2hseHuBe36FeHuCcnV6cHF2we0nSQAAKPRJREFUeNpUe4OfZVmW7raOdX3jhu2ItO2sLNu22bat8XSPuse2+Wzb9vsL3rduTefLKf0yom6cs/fCh7V3MBGzLNXWcK25yoVQPBZMOsasTISLShN5aU2rdVNpypJ57qNu+tzFT/RuntzUUu6NGXMy6/Fv/dD5v7ezh4tHh8dnlh6dnDu3fC70hdUs1CF3WnEuBLc1Y4rVgtkqkcwxHlWOGZsk3Nq0YlUqrJAu9UoVy/5oqZX0Ix+1Cnll5SCT5/wdXnGbPCLEtGILvZ6ykWKFL9xNJio8495rpbzBZpRLsC6mo7Lkxljsx6WVMKlmmVROCfbM9tbuptBB38N5quKN02/sZzU32Dxv87rWIUc8tHCcaREmTKOZjmMVN1wYjf/FPFPSMpZWFRaZBW6wA26c4IJrpY36bP+hB5XGloWKIptM73mAMW1cJYWRJZaXMckSCjHTTIqS2Y4XrMNiyyrGsowbISVe6ZzMdagncoadaeVi/IdZrfx/Prl4wAShNZ7h7NKJawdmzYcOX7jjXunlHYYdtrbrpjcPL2KNnMWFxiY1AhIbUWFjQiPOzCK/zml8nSuHvWsTCSkqk5rt3R9/8NLsW5xJhew6m23dt++4zmcmR7+eT+4M9PmB6B96ju89tZGgIiytP3VS4tGGO50HEVMceJ0ryXPEA0m11ik/xbFa59jMAT/3zsI0y4SOlXImSLX0KB+NjvGd/OD3HdMvPXr+3EPP5geW7gnMMno+q7B/x+NKdpJEokpp/VlsnA2qShLrjDLcFEIqJZ2YGx7tf6KHjwmdWRc5Nlzp7VNq+wdmBwtXe28tPLi3994f7e+/cDFMMpVJBF5UVspUMi8LxhVLrKQ4B1O5WLpM4PlccotictZEnC0b/hOcQocKjcpUqXRWy4FYEijtbDQ6PyN2f7wXf/6BlwbIc5V0UCnIZwc1b8skk6gKVI8NuVKqqVl7QkuueDBeGIMKCZpzZMigAiXK2CGJFQ/OCRSUtowbfNussvhIgnqJom40VURTPlItz41Pk8QYZjwiLTKUPVellGgP72XaZd45VerIMNZJXJIgjsxVlrMqE6gurjPsVqk6E36VN0WznmP9xpfelFhZZQV3FsnVMedSmxCUdQI9q00lGd4WUUGht70TAT0f4kA4UqE0SsZtxWQmUJ9oU2uLrtKXs6AYFwGhDQZbdthwVTFVGumLsmgZX6xORelHItdabQGF0oKn3ivH7lj06imO/MYdtG/hlLnAktkfFAOme6iMXi708h8t8zJBKlEYpoPyk+gmLXJgUI2CF7aSNucmSo25SVo8vzCm+zywpvQumd7d6n+YSaQhFSydOjxc+7czk5M/3D9l+sN7zcLG/f148sTG/qv9PuqHc0CMMioWNgAjZLvJ8yfzwJvw9nqe86bBdzS3wL+0K6y1ieNn5w8dHNwmBcpCJM4Nlpb2/Nibc2f2zRw4NuIHHzmw796D0rpPlSc2jzIpjfHeSCdZimQgfzJSmnusvx0UR1HY0ChrtY7TAuittdXz9NFbFLA5ZYlL5ZK6XR9H8cwMUUJyWj69ssPk9vZgba2HigfCU3yYRBKZtSLzMlZp5H3QykTSpzx4lzKRdEo0GtIU7xde924DloqUGmzAh2Yp1iMxIzkj7sgXn2Bn2MCs/IYBvvnIoCyMMRV2UhRAbclNGbm0YcJ2UH86B/yLWEQu8Z4DUXhWXjx76LDruiljo+KL87d8I8kQLYABw4aSttQhzgVKJqb3oXc54AHgGGtjNIq6Qcdau55rYYBtyLpy+XotZQ2Ab+v1unYxuwWFnMsYqD/7tLYZPS3HExoCf8QK7+MSnRGj1oHBCqhp8BlFMcrayFpaxEwhOL602hdd7Kk7BZ50pgWMLjemv7RoS9P1JioPb33zlz1qxJuiiKzxPDfMYpdSoQ/RgKm0+NtljkkLsNRcTKBDbPo5rMEDFaSQtgBPpynSz1SqZRKpPVsAROYS5Yv3sskKbDJev66b0F4PeR43WgcwFfoTH5P4KzMEWBykp9eBnK76HMghCugojoeAWcoyQ/qFbYP4ji/968nciJSwb43teuJaNBNQBOnLFb3ORAbfUswX+LaPIlmYolvgiwgUXLTKrvYWkFlGIH2bqqCQewOgTtGELfPID1/hhS2ABt4cXYwQG8MCqp0lJqnR2RrowmMNfEDt0fKdkIAmDj7WYQIUyN2dWcZcKAEdyqTYxFRBG2U2FsLN9Y7t/JSKUyCtnP9ZxJAQDF2KiMushjpAJzirkYjEdfBw1H+skN8Q2k2o3243Mmc/MtGeCE/yEAv0AzAjgj5BSbi8jRo53dsWVVIlAJ/o0NHfAo2hMhgzScJEO8uA1LEBhoO9ADXAfSVJGHA0CKg2GFO6quYy+JCajCU+xf+KOmg/yX0cBxUePNZHdvEGqBc5D3aqCGl4ZCXCC9hkCTKD5/Na2RjSgOsaKY81b0Din2OuMFQnsYvpyTwqJAMbjHFbtTn3y/MHZoQillF69uBwCPWH19ZCxTnn6yFjLIZew4tQ+hXVqKUOsGONaNnnGGrbByliKyD/0BpO6aTyiUSEXa2ZWRwso6rQG1H0mFreu4Yy4QmHXECITI4iiqDXHIeO0pQTiD6H/RFdCEigGgsuIrwM4shx4nGnQjAW1IOPTwTg3KOjn4cGcNpIuXv64BqHkNABLJYxI9sMZQVY9syw0hetqJiaQmECLVEpgquwHrQ0OgjeKJ2yDJtPoescAoued23AiGIPzg3QvDxSfHk4XANlQ9YAPYWQCDEKLVERPT/FT2iObnJISmSJnAuD/LqOEwmrsX4JnYlQ143KJ5oaWPJkAFQdP7/zNJYYS/bz/M3zX2va6Nm6qRFlwhs8H+Bi8XwIHwRxairFbtDw4ErlkTflUugQimqKfZESBTBbBpjxEVjVLT60BcBRpAjUgr+yIDMIB2hYnqP9m1hDHEDW16RyhHtXdBsuIPm5hvhpW1ulETKFvVB/AXShgCCk0IdMtqEJ2LbcYDJBtmRvia9tQPDlIcS1yUHiE4Iy6QsvI9JWTkXdbgGBoiIpqQBUiKKyO4ZCr0oPNEmsZTFkgySf8DZU/vDhxycBXzwItrszd3JEvYl1QHSgDCfigGpFsmLslErGpGmEegzUIgxvQSrTDjwAeocBGVBAxoFsILszAGwbPycu7rkPL2f4vOw/fveHDIBdohCroEV2ZzJmGgCnZzeVWGlraqosAZHofuCJS+LKUsA5rQoKC0hrOdaEf2vebp6Ugu8/PqohBNoTzUT+tbl5dI6ichYO7ioZ2yAIIqhuYmqE05UUYA07wFkGYet0BLWI6gfTo6VDDl4LeJ2CslYNOFr0Xl5jgG6sWe1ZeIGwmAHeUI7QO1yiDmwRtRBtRzoGtAiLMrGO9IPZ8HzLUnSshsRkLSDrmLWhXfAGk4gauMv7uwdIqAqbHF/ahYwV9E0BYAJB5SRQtR0LhilD8F+UURmRXBVjCRyA8ugmYcn/aNXETZC6DhSQMNF+G16kN5rb92qeN3moXxyNvjyjMsRSocOavBYTyDzCOYbUCnADvQ//YMWdgXqWKYFwQ1IA5qHUS+guMDayDMQ1UKNiArX22R93p0YSNstm2d869IfPrKZjIIhASfC6tvDoVJNKDeULVQsRoxDgt3Mdg3sMjIu2eH6M7+kILcg4mgJ2BVYI/qNNbbig9jDCYMuSs/4z4+LuFhG4kGoKLlly1CCj51OyYUIqJmqIKGAZAm9RQdgdzCovgXciTpyFHihLCcVW66adj54+jkpvgNDxfTOvUZHYyGDRLBDDcEaPqQQIEKAEPe4McBJMRVhp4kaRNER+VYBCxC4giAxLuOuwUjFS5VJNymUJRvJcfvSh37wFmZNmXHGNEAFdBx6WHeg5KGC4WGh/AAUeD2ZDvcBFOpmqhGxRR5ZAJpbCi0NOM+A6/ItSe9kBhAc8bYYLMwv7IdhgcaB2oGPI9KJTDQl91pWR9Qn2lkoek/fFPqEBwcipJDnCXGagwhjIJeZg1BTaANp0r+3PY40ASXP40HzaRzAtIZgRpHtyLREakCJnLZQjcCVVSGCNIkZ127qtG5ANmU+wWSzjuInfbTAnIHRjCC453d/AYkGGWr3/iRMgFXgPQAnAFt7N+QIOMVqFkbLtpmFNIJvB4oRsEPxOApzDNjRqCAUMzsgh6EQtbQWTk4u8nevJfn8O5IrG7C2PFnYgbLB+gD8KhLSnzDihDZi0rRq93gAYUDYgaTJ10AsgyC4CGCnfwovQUBFcQVS2EEbGIt9tlfeSSMB65e7RA98AjYlKEiMllESRGZJU4DZma1UDVFNFM5+EOqYqITtFB7I0tng3r8N6PTERiMBkByI1z4Hrd/h7j/WxVAgTtkwiJxMd8DlXiUiSLEuoqRC0BPjmqIdpPGATMAZaLSWJDgFNin0i1nX+JESrwfOJD63IA7rYLaws9QXaBwi+K79BLFR6qERSQyhU2hf8ByxUqlKwNLg4ApEoY6UvC3QcCDglCsUjobIQCmfgWOFNLdALKs4NPvHGUgb09sXi8PTmRTQ7NKABRDPKAJwj3gC0QL9UNOmRlHqyIIl0JVGYKVfT6tZV2zrSnfKrHddKy06rWLWFCknqyzuiQ/p+KDJWB77//vlYZWKs5MYOBsWvII4MfDX4sSNdnBHdAP5qfFzbPEaqDSydrQKtKSgIOawcqpHcEXC3Uw3uYtTtFfC2d2xTeZZ0DCrI08DH4w9kPQrsJuWpNTEj++EpcrLodvFHFbVAwEULrIE3IKDE6chvArmSpKYVLUdmSEVPUHfMIcNJBe2OgofAQf9ZV6a+FVlo1BTIDOxGYrGJrAY0B4gNtBzA09EIDBWPVYJNkHP0ImBbptGVw1/eQZ5SMOjgIKQGZ8QmkHQycJ+wjMPzRgxxwQM1tCgnpSoIvOAV0V9oLpCjyWnUBE2A8tSQldCDaH4L4OC/cPoBPB+6d3n3xZOv6lBLaEfoMKwGqhmKA6KG3CkvkIUEiaE5ixS5gtaPKQEWToPXOVgLegk1KUXlHOAa4pL5avmZ08B1mWYZXxKHJfEtPBDSmaB5E7QYEAh0xAodARkSiCCYEOBfjM3H0KkcwMYswS4QG0gDIQ2R6wIeIAtbXvCfmSWqwPMFu/hPySqirCEHYbzY2EbYBKIMKosjG6j7QhWQQOQiFIUYkJBmMb1RxglJJGhlMGlHdJT0HPZv8pOnUeyeROT0+59icHKl8hFwGBmIJDjMwDBAg1gajZEMR0FyUjgqWAQ75rFsTwCPcqAqOh24TxF0NDL18C2dwdVj5+NcOp3xf3bsKQKiAgSc3pqmrf8AMVW2WlF6+UjKAiR4QLgBNhaKC6oaTKawX1kyjS9UhFouuuiWwreAeSWqNvJT//I7Fw4N8dQUBXzl6AukgbuK/J0E0OMLxJZxlZKBINCAQWQVKNdQ3oFVIHntwIowfFSbhubFpGdcTGXngH4IwmTCfYfLvcNJ+RKkionJfugxDaLiVAymJSJzkjjBcWhQaETfal023poiinhARwF7ICzRpqAxqHZREawkZWr/lxt4d3kqiqLNe5/CojPAriTdCTpHQICoEFyahZzn7QbYOIHKDfn6nU0DxGzaSIcIwvA2fkCN1+8JSRJqQqsjN/nCsR3whUUN3SLvliZSUwgkIiJpqstoGmHJOGD9StCoG/wDsoNBAQIF5JeOBJDYNuJDwt2CVSChTIn6qViZyt+5/Teg+7rGffaRT5kZrWuPz0HxcYAnzVA9zYJQrSBZrEFUcUWQFyP6NLgAzaCsoBiCJCXmyQLILgxUldHJQDfNfnX3h4SWHezmtvm70dBJCwsnB4oUIIHJu+KdQXEbATtgoWqqCkmRoAWH2k3xXmgaxAdmD/AFKVjSfJLqlBUR+36zz5iIZo3qPpq9oL8sy6qx0hqPmcbjaQQK3hlOD+uX0I4xaXJoBtCAJMPvagQNPhe9FxXPp7e2bnVdX4KNh//lxM3vMy0A7GA4N2rnNHPikADoITiABCElwS5Jx8EZmMzVFsICz1dxHCvAWkSDc2HhBRneCxSlKSoBMQWhisT3z98DkoAU5ZNP3IX2FiUQsU5JJ1BpAtCpF6GdETUaLgVLqr3hRLkWYVoFe6Lyya9pKG2yYCV6gCYE6OIy+TeDJbhA2CY2mn+fREkfgV6z3YL0vqJSInMIOjAoClBgy7Q8mW5AEDQbHtwCZKEi4Hfgi6kH8UEgJP1cJdMp9R/3zGC/wPZ6P18ZRl4eKcCHALMWzASoHnKxRF2g/AgahET9o1kDJBvKHl3hNY38TKAyQ36xCdsBg8PRqpRDw1w4KNBwkLJibnIXwdMkn0mv0CgVUdMBmB7TfE+Tu3I5XCcN1z05JPRDCxoGQojGXNh8BiC1QBCQONSD7qTJLx/oK2vgl8W+0Qy3knhQJtW7NtLSQDFABLEwXr/RaaDG08x6CHjEx6GcdVAmp3m/pjBoPtY1MaBXp+n96SN8GZBe+MPvnXkU/NUwGGxIzXbQTRMClMIEhCtJncICTNGbEZhMFoWxtoslT0HaC+fBppwGZBLonpZFkUrkSztz/2Nro0uoP2DXyY052IPcQcQGgIAinq3bsGsurkEM0oOuTaoVzQOg6QBTnYSZKR8xCFBNkoPRcYal+EAL0JircOwPb37YKPgPLbcnaW7N4UfHZAXOQdmCcUUL/AumhOm0vCIWtAzphP6uQJ9dOiDEjyl4bk7wU9BMqCjRjDIpq34BVAcqJNDck++HKA6RsiGHpA75ne3QhoVqTN7gM9TwQHYN4pQySNqdw/MvUwVQ78E31XkeQENSNoy3eS7xOPHC+9FKnPwIu/m3QLV1CiXIKloNQRqNsloACmNNCUS0HUHaBWYCbMZSWMVb6YgPBgm0DzceWXDeR1Zbq6s0KWUdN/r8yoFFqNpE+WFvHtIiOGVpMAiPUoeAeuDBY/1SyTQBSZSIgELqoNm1gSmztwLYqLcNrAJWw73i3RIO0lIZtPxGcXSI4iGhcPLK4cWpUnXTsmQptEXh4VSt9VGXnJUmBWV0ldCRGtiSTElXWv8RFC19oyOJHgToARWuLRpOMN3x6jO2DyECpTEarqwsolKnWlOg54KRcC4Mzfla8ABYFxichAX+KfBHtJ7rgq3+mvXcAjchIrFHOsg1Uzf5Lnpe6czZbfuTDzJQKwpwbsHupjbuVJUD1UE6IYGCzuhaoHnAi6P1k/djkjQOtFQaa3lE0EhS0gCV5BicYdZJM7KxKODUs0dsj9OADPH/+jPvmwLu0JETHXhDYZQR2ti0wKo0PMkANXgr7I2lkTpek2XySIb4wHRbLJeYCHajk9KwetySXd+6d4gOBNW62x6LAH0chQ/ANISd6AIGvXwro/SoAqmIEIZWYaaqyKFUptC/z6P+RQeeneRciHNIUZMGQ+sHUnv51Jd34PTHOnXvPGGaNdZxO555jeHTRx8B25W3lpexJZQCAzSUGtxMg1dmjwgI6A6wGSKe0894uzrlbr1cRUBAw0fT02cvrLaQoAuXDs33nYATqVI67iVuh2RmvnyeFLAVBpAFYMXaWKqJcRzwwR6hM69K05QuF3UDGRPQoDRGThKo3ZnBcG0vvEhhWov/s9xskRlZvQmWAiVORo8ODr+K8HijAL6MzkcpBQ3sdlvDVekS2iZGbPBJDUIl8nYQAXQQFmJZ//EoPHsc0Qm1mVzG8jQdVqJ+6IBe0UF8ZtOvZniBJoUf8J+3Gzj5iYl2EwcGxVUEQ2PSmousftdUmaJURYG6EAngXfb6MiLtnT40/UEaJaZlmnLUG5140uUJ476aKVZ5iDKkR6k2sUoIoHe6iKBLTUdVoYbZmICSI2dibM5BmAILmcjvmdE9xBlGcW3P8GGTxdAuMAdwxL5yYx/pvgAnctfvbV59rjc/b/33dSQv6HxKItnGHzFeP7cJs6J6Q857vy+XsrunxYIaJgzwopnsATXoYMiefW3rDWwIBEIWoCUhY1EqED7Pc8fc7dei/rW1aw8thI5MOnGWAadR9roIMz/94ty/++m5r8XN1/Jz8cz+/cONew7yM/thJmFaZ2/DSjr25MDd9oubS3RU0HHoKllxLA/GmtnOEWxm8KkL3358Re29+aq+Q9mSKpHClUDOr+mz9+0sbS315/pivzi4/1Guz/1s/+z3zWiyrA8v3fNP7pzcxz/wpVtOWfCvsADQmI40BM2pkdnqq2ih/nM/8cJvDyyf3Iw7KqtyTdYM2o615l+eWZzd1/f9AeLz2/1t8WPszdGJwd//pcfXkQK+NMn3yc3t7dO2v2eNDte4M1GmaNJh9FibybQBfopo+oGVFc4WwqH8VY7yacejTUBqtHHzzBfXWPIT0kzDb8IaC7Yze/V9qyxqa3DMGyNxD1976JEv+uWjp1bohP6m7vPg8lQSRiAIqlwNnl0/thz9yeE12HEQJpufvgSI2To78n0tqvGMky6UsKS23h8R8zS0kRd7IpjHpjdhy//uWaQ5FpWM6OIEerGu2xPttvY/krPrx5YXHv1+j+cnQvROHoIWcmyw8XFFA1jZGd9qAUFDKNkjEPPMBCVvnrlHLrz+5j3hpx/Ux2GkwA0FUNbReRndJoKEmlDs+rHlU+ffNxPbHC8fQpehDuRXxNWHE9aJCYhiMGqS1M7ZI4FBFumIT8bPioUz/Wm7cXL4BMP6AYoQJgarJ9UFeXu5bdkNx5aHBihKKKPRxibJQT7Qe5bQcjGJeyAa3YSpjPkCM5o7Gk3Xoe+O3v6d6AOnLPRh4GCoDA4gg4NnhBy2QH6vH1tebd7hscvrpvmWHj4LF/bqzD77AKf5dond0+xLhdT754XMYRLYNrae/OBrx+52e4+e5OOhuZJ1qGWzTuIEf3NL8f/useWg/977hbqTsblt9uCktZEQQyCGjig+WTw2/hoa83lt6sRq1n9oZRC976EX/sUzh05tgIdB1mhXySNaCKoBKFc0nl0/trT6VMDzwX7JE8dnnEpfeeLoNZOIlqChQtyRGXDZ2eoIKM6ULlp+yw3VxqT8oz0fW/SHIYGh91I6aeKMyJ2MUVQTm//5seWpub/xbBzWm/yeF5/+4/sNj75XzH2A1t9o2W6eJEXWbnQToonvrU0k1aykM5Hw8787+tiZWZMwbR25vSwiwWkj4Jap/gdg4rvHlrPioyAXLv3i1rGZwTN+Cvvc3MbnSceHhscwyQFSt6XpYgcW+Phr3MPOnLj4384wn2SxhMFnWnhySLHNYEhc27Drx5bTc4uQg9jO4aOXDvRSV3DWO6v28iKTlQ7aCEbGRoK0twKezifPDIOKAyi6lLuoF0A3fFWo6RgE8iCDu7ITELR/fmw5q56d/bQWTS74PrH/aWtcEz98ZpeLlO6lhdxmSEKGRK0y05B57sk96FjBOtmJXo9RYn1Bt/GO+OKy910avpV5yr57bLn1yEtP0QkgU/09p7aWerKOhZ9e3FQps6nQdHATYrrGUGZyXZCIHw4W6ecr9qtn71VJghZwLgGuIz4ZHTRBWj7J2f8/tvyTtSADkvhpUsD7OXYy/XNzF5Myge8iEaboTIvLVb63TbfXJDs7qEsWSll+akC33egeiwLKeV+k7ohbvRytqoJ999hyxZ97hzmVZWJ05eWbRyNbi+xnDlx8haWJjAw0I6e7AS5hNAbwRHAP3a6aKH7Wnt88yJcVeU0aVLEptCTUGItQQORZrh9bPv11Xjo6eBj85MFzQk3kYjCzRPjGIhMYDVLHB2JRBijAkxbNlz7Ju3L2hf61Xh9fcwfahZrvku0nlpcwduiE68eW//iDsSO/o49tTP4Ykliz3909Pck6sEqOehiIBbAmC78OjR+PxBnJS3b6e3r+l97UoZ2jR3mmtSdHkjka3fBcsevHlg//8/mssgkMywf29ieXF0Hhd//cbZMcPVPaeHwwCi8pYhMrDjXp7njP1Vltnp77xPBvn4ouFEYC58nCdRNLJ1nC0Nm7YdePLX+omRUwgEqEnZ0/+Af5KEzUvfycHiEkBR3z0tUXZAFg4da54VlvuKB4ymemJ80SvwtxqJyCWVRHJM0HCm4MIChi148tZ88N6PkI1NFDw9um4ZPYYfyAghVM8Q7ToIkDz6Fz9ToNGsW+R2ySDm9/Z/apByA4AORQV8DAVkKDi1QbyPIARPjusWW/T6MdmPfzNw/377cPo2hXjo9GT2DtLaTd0+ULA+GEbOnIeuavXL0Cv3DL9OSJ/nAaGpOkOww78Jwu5YyHq8CR7x5bfrp+6SRNfDh7WO3Lz5/8U9Tn4f5orm9FArcrqdZiWzGDFK9jYRN6+LPbzD2xu6L/7JZTdxRerd5UttJWcROoPkL/li0rJd1/e/fYsv9/4eIvl9Vq58T0z23P/8IaAviX7MKZ18+IJFJBMDRkTv0F6groF22u/dc/ZYCWt7R72N5l6YIgIRSDt4VGc2I8jici+PNjywe+NbCexnLywJn+4OODvcb+994GIxdZ0skG3QvAK3K6+uqBuXt+7Ve8KQfLV/Q3+nLa8SCRBBpCQTrzpENHOnTh5fqx5QNvDumIyoo53ntWTz8AHZu+0e/PjITo0lU3wXlNLQSnEQPm2vLkyTXg0MxgKT229xLWnkaMDo9T0qZJldH8EV8v9J4buk7vmVl2fJ5koQqj3s0zy4f3zDBW3MKHgyEgTaIIkLTakr3I0dqN/qujuSeGECEz09mJR98MLM6tg+oW3Mc3Xnlmfti/cupnxMr+nXwDjleIWiSP75v92A8sJSbd5rPz8z12x0D0Bn2kwA5mQ9jhaHLVfOjMR+Gi+Mah1/1oHwq3cRI/HRsf33jlmX3szIsfXdiafM/ByaFJpcxYW0x++L7hM/fOc1mJvjJff3nvZw4d+PjHP7Hyya0ffeGOS5Ozr+f0/A/OPgYV1pcnFv7KtQVfeveF1YJGbUfSG688s82bj28ecGvXJFtRKWyBhFn5ytJx+waVQhB8+/aDky8zcTtbmDndu9r79/Nz8/dpy404uvkY0JjL6fuuvrwMHyxSsCN0GLzzDVeemR3s+0H52Eq0JWhwhvXj+dO9/lMJV3ADSfack71Dr8/tSU68KoZpf3T3i18xVWv1clredQkyLQ+z+946+hhcvpqi49NEVeIvXHlulRxcD2oACqfwokYnGeyFI7npdEZImCGw+E4bik8klahMBioPao2Gb4DJV85+YEgHU7CSBlKtI/7ClecyZaVydIPSqJSulgdAGFwvSwwrNc15ad6boOKgmiM4stxAe0VKL3P764FuzPX33L4GAZi4SAGHAGk3XnkGxtUS+UL+72wzmQu6/uzGV4otLVdyh13zRLKqYUAt9EdVZbDQ8fTcawgpNEPvypUFg091gD8RvHly45VnmL0EDE78ZVTZjYyCfSXq58pQL0MpQZlZW3ga75cMgShbsPtSV/NW0t0+I5b2xa8q3aAzaqAxgOqGK89Q56ar0sjQqUkV0QU7qOOxi3V0NwjGAqCS0cwerqVCuLRxaStN09955535lKYZw+UFa+hSO36aZlj6xivPrCyjrixphhoh/vDyNdLI6OIZRLfgWULTScCzTMmJ+GK1KPAclcSbJ1+DecaC1ubYKxxC30EG+Cj19sYrz7AWdOgBZk5kNr4p2LyrxAB66E66bgd/lDBY9pr7EvCl+NgqCTa3S3QfAxOW+tg8tDUqwTr7F648gzDJBFss08sCyA2poDxCLzt021+IXMSgh3Y75uuBLsehdukwDa2vBz6lec8HH9xGmtBfqGk1voB2w5VnZqyy9CsUifCUi0Ll9HqamkV0YJgIOm8QcRzrCQgc6BSQH12Z4rOw9RUddT03M9mDRJLdrqVCT82NV55JmoPxsElt4jRFUu+ki3Eofgoz6kd6C8JGIfo8orkimpRfaB12dy3ebudJOYlXerM9C81QUt3CAKobrzxDvxm6BSWCplMVKMg2o4muzCIT6wBbQlRO91H5BH461mgi3tuUP5kNxOz4+ECayYN7bM/xRXWOq70Gvd274cpzt1u26CYZ4xWdmnlWZ4LuItWeQ1RoCikpK6iYJyEihIqUEFvTu+rFgxC8oc7rfP/5bXfvN1c2Vtbmrqxc/easW3hi2Z+a3rKPM3k3o6mchToyNlXdMvIoTTqOUqQVUSd0Ok5noYhj29AdLgCN+M2vL02L+bnd8QlQLM6de3x77vQc2zmvz8/xc8fCH8weGL2+tfmh5eXX6HwH7ASfIKwGQNGV5QzrlVlquET1BHAO3YqMogZ1JkzXc75yWFz4/WUqPS6TmvV3ohOHBnf9wG23DLbf7x6/bV5M37IhDq6c5r05mrZB1SF/NsL6S6VRP5A6yC9VT4z6STRdijK8jQ/B1iueuZJFWAG8p4wgnnR+2Bt+lSWcJRc3JZv89F10zhvt8ZeG7MZfhsHzIYiANpGL0o+0EC3jTYG+LC1wR9MBdNHykpAS+JgANhLwugqhhVTCV0MExChd265Ukv2jliv+Mur/hl+GKSPA3p10jUnnsdfjizw5sD/AbHDUP90BsDAfRvKKJr+Apwqkz8IUcKIcnzpC0wre0DVqX0hD51CsoF+GcbaIbLdA0HNgAem4FnUpKI6kT6R54XPnTerh9Nndd8u7XpF0FQ90MBGa9RXevpO/VN//va/+FKfnG1SejxK6OacDzR4IHlQCWEQl0nkX6uIy/WpDyIKIRc7JBWJVgi5mcL5n8P7pi3xnZ3wfMw/3rC/sTi4N1pJt+dy2ZNsrwX+QLmxkFt4E+hPqExKU61BYF5oJuiMSJkJJU3mWBDpBsQLquw02t7YDifszA/V/dntziGoiEFxen/jFjb47xO5bUPMfvTT44oy/dvEiQGzxw/uRJnyMTroIV9JU0nhU+yTWt9Iokdob4AX1Wk4FKI6imGr5aPLBg+9dMD0aJUsu3svqldfk6OzJW8zywssLl05fOn/pPT322MLwwx8+x0DWAjGo86Bzn8JANkguF3kooMNykUP2A9vCurYTStRaO5VrNT96XOwHZIUYclTfP3F2dnbmK6fF5EgdWz4wWv6p2+VxvXjq2J75mJEGQvPScUNIq4p2ktV0wt+lYx1Bl2pFrETDXW7pMAJaXR3Ygr6nI3DCMeaV/uz0lpjuiV5v+Mrdcmf4aTmb9avBbXcNnmYkiBu0Q855njrSvFLCEHHZpe0D28R43JVz13CATW6RsAWLjsc3USsGLSfjVZjFlA5DaE4Eq0PX2NfWduxWgP65qShX8eTSpc/f1CokNHvb8CZEdR3X9QSZj6bJ14Ns6LBBpDIR7/nYG5ZufsiAXaNx2gU8jeV0iYiuG5uG0uKs6BSApybkQEtNxzZlRQMCxnPIAnmTRfMqunCGLjVBuQASBQTxEPuj+yUbwR3SJToIhmc9+gBIEOt8gjUT+duQuzTwoqv9opbjW4cElqXzxFZ0q1pDwcCLkfCneTG8csoLGux3I2m3zshrbu9eDi7FGqLFnc/MLu79ttlrHnuLl6BZXXSjbil5C4oIsGJoMtFplekXui20ADi4jCTrMtJ05OwFp8uvKV3gcTY1jC/+J7ZV9QZwR5QAO3jRbrD+Xf19Q907/tTgdfcS9nlpbbTze+Yl6GUf6ABT0mVnH9FdZ0lXjvK01nGu2xPtvKkh77TT15/PDx5ffuRlD08pTdFd/OR9n9yzMZw+8OX3vHXzqY//mf07Mx9yajG6d/Dtz68wliNIdDgDz1YYMDcSHOjGbYcOoa2m+8bjm8YpTxGLtPTefeeC+9/P/MqiikiuWbY1e+303PKg98Bt/VcObJ1g75nZunbQ20/tPbo4x278ZRgI0faTWPCTOrQBW6gbDRe/ju8AQCAsAhQKvLIYfGBn9CjdQ2jnmgTlvkW1NGtmN+b37O5+Kb39HTn9PSe/5x/+zV/70c8DW2/4ZZjUpONfedMF5LqnmxLSivGv2RlBVwMl5BPd4oJ+wWbLKOK2vLVVXjZ/fWWw+MLiDy9Gh3r/6g6+9/773Ozmvn37ps3S/xNgANvv2d/o0uEhAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')}
```

It's "pure CSS", right? =D

See: [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Examples)

Edit:
Looking at the comment you left on Evan Mulawski's answer, here is the decoded PNG of my base64 string:

[image]

I just copied a portion of the image you provided in your question. It doesn't tile 100% seamlessly, but it looked "good enough" for posting inside a base64 string noone would *ever look at*.

```
body {background:url(background.png)}
```

Comment: Yes, that's helpful. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the texture works, you might be able to do it by creating an insanely large number of positioned `<div>`s with borders in various shades of gray.

## Don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in CSS.  You need to make an image and repeat it on the background.

http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/design/photoshop-tutorials-textures/

Comment: Brad, thanks for the link.  I can find PLENTY of photoshop texture tutorials myself.  I'm looking for this specific texture. :)

Comment: @Kevin Brown, then talk to the person that made it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set the background image property using a tiled image.

Filter Forge (filterforge.com) has a filter library. See if you can find a suitable image there, then use repeat-x and repeat-y for a seamless background.

Comment: He's asking how to do it without an image.  (I assume)

Comment: And, as your answer and Brad's has stated, it's not feasible without using an image.

Comment: Welp, if I can't do it with just css, where can I get this texture?

Comment: You can try Google Images for ViewFlipside Background, but you may not find a seamless tile. Check filterforge.com for a similar image.